# How do I make count return 0 with group by 5 min if no records appear in that group?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
select case when count(distinct player) > 0 then count(distinct player) else 0 end as 'num',
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp2) DIV 300) as '5m', 
GameID from table_4 
where Timestamp2 between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-02'
group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp2) DIV 300, GameID
```

My data structure looks like:

```
player          date               GameID
  1        2018-05-10 00:00:00       1
  2        2018-05-10 00:01:00       2
  3        2018-05-10 00:02:00       3
  4        2018-05-10 00:03:00       4
  2        2018-05-10 00:06:00       5
```

And I tried to get:

```
 num            5m                 GameID
  1        2018-05-10 00:00:00       1
  1        2018-05-10 00:00:00       2
  1        2018-05-10 00:00:00       3
  1        2018-05-10 00:00:00       4
  0        2018-05-10 00:00:00       5
  0        2018-05-10 00:05:00       1
  0        2018-05-10 00:05:00       2
  0        2018-05-10 00:05:00       3
  0        2018-05-10 00:05:00       4
  1        2018-05-10 00:05:00       5
```

My code doesn't show up row 5 when GameID 5 is not played in the first 5 minute.
I'm new to mySQL, and I have tried for several days and still didn't solve it

Thanks for everybody

Comment: You must have some recordset with all 5 GameID values which you want to obtain (static table, generated table, CTE, etc.). Then LEFT JOIN your source table to it, and group by its GameID field, not by the field from source table. Server cannot return the data which is absent.

Comment: What exactly is "Timestamp" and "Timestamp2" in your code ?

Comment: And use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp2) DIV 300 )` instead of `FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp2)/300 )` in `5m` field expression too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select m.fivemin, g.gameid,
       count(distinct t.player)
from (select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp2) DIV 300) 
 as fivemin
      from table_4
     ) m cross join
     (select distinct gameid
      from table_4
     ) g left join
     table_4 t4
     on t4.gameid = g.gameid and
group by g.gameid, m.fivemin;
```